# Cannot get data for first render in Power BI custom visual (React)

Tags: reactjs, powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

After insert my custom visual

```js
export class Visual implements IVisual {
  constructor(options: VisualConstructorOptions) {
     console.log("constructor");
  }
  
  update(options: VisualUpdateOptions) {
     console.log("update");
  } 
}
```

When user first open this view, only `constructor` is called, until user has other interactions, e.g. resize the page, select other filters, etc, the `update` method is called.

But I need this custom visual to be rendered when user first landing on the page, I checked the doc (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/visuals/power-bi-visuals-concept)
[image: Custom visual]

It does not mention that the `update` will be called at first render, so how can I get the data when a user first lands on the page?

Currently the only way works for me is to manually call `options.host.refreshHostData();` in constructor, but I'm not sure whether is a correct way of doing it.

My env:

1. Power BI service with custom visual (React.JS)
2. pbiviz v5.4.2